# Program is saying every number is prime number

Tags: c

I have created this C program that is supposed to tell me how many prime numbers are between 1-25, but it is printing that every number is prime number. Please Help

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {

int n = 1, counter = 0;
int i, flag = 0;

while ( n <= 25 ) 
{
    for ( i = 2; i <= (n/2); i++ ) 
    {
        if (n%i == 0) 
        {
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 0) 
    {
        counter++;
        printf("%d is Prime Number.\n", n);
    } 
    else 
    {
        printf("%d is not Prime Number.\n", n);
    }
    n++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
flag = 0;
```

Your flag is always `0`. You have to set it to `1`, while entering the `while` loop

```
while ( n <= 25 ) {
    flag = 1; //<-- here
    for ( i = 2; i <= (n/2); i++ ) {
```

You can as well `break` in the segment, just for *efficiency*

```
if (n%i == 0) 
{
    flag = 0;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code as,

```
for ( i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++ ) 
    {
        if (n%i == 0) 
        {
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 0) 
    {
        counter++;
        printf("%d is Prime Number.\n", n);
        flag=1;
    } 
    else 
    {
        printf("%d is not Prime Number.\n", n);
    }
    n++;
```

use `sqrt()` instead of `n/2` program will be more efficient.